# What are the "elements" in "the elements will melt with fervent heat"? NKJV. 2 Peter 3:10

Tags: greek, word-study, hebrews, 2-peter

Here are 3 possibilities:

- c.2000 years ago in Greek culture the elements were fire, earth, water, metal and wood.
- To the modern scientific mind, as when the N.K.J.V. was written, elements may bring to mind the periodic table of elements. J. MacArthur uses such words as "atoms, neutrons, protons and electrons" to explain "elements" in this verse.
- In Gal 4v3 stoicheia is translated as "elementary principles". "we were in bondage to the elementary principles of the world, [the fall]. ..Elementary principles can refer to the way the world works, Gal 4v9, or, "the first principles of the oracles  of God", Heb 5v12.  ..Either way physical elements are different from elementary principles.

If the elementary principle of the fall is destroyed then the physical earth can remain as Psalm 104v5 "that it should not be moved forever", [moved from its present course].  ..The new earth then becomes the old earth renewed, rather than the old earth physically destroyed and replaced by another.  ..Are "elements" in 2 Peter 3v10 best seen as physical elements, or, elementary principles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What are the “elements” in “the elements will melt with fervent heat”? NKJV. 2 Peter 3:10**

From Vine's Expository Dictionary of NT Words (On-line)

1: στοιχεῖον "elements"

(Strong's #4747 — Noun Neuter — stoicheion — stoy-khi'-on )

In the NT it is used of (a) the substance of the material world, 2 Peter 3:10,12 ; (b) the delusive speculations of gentile cults and of Jewish theories, treated as elementary principles, "the rudiments of the world,

2 Peter 3:10  (RSVCE)

> 10 But the day of the Lord will come like a thief, and then the
> heavens will pass away with a loud noise, and the elements will be
> dissolved with fire, and the earth and the works that are upon it will
> be burned up.

A literal interpretation of Peter's words would mean that the heavens with its billions of stars and galaxies and everything else will be consumed by fire and intense heat, and just because on a tiny planet like earth live rebellious wicked humans. God does not intend to destroy what he created, the physical earth and heavens will remain forever  (Psalm  89:36-37,  104:5).  Such a view also contradicts the words of Jesus and the Psalmist.

Matthew 5:5  (NET Bible)

> 5 “Blessed are the meek, for they will inherit the earth."

Psalm 37:29  (NABRE)

> 29 "The righteous will inherit the earth  and dwell in it forever."

Peter’s words do not apply to the literal heavens and earth. They refer to a great tribulation (Mat. 24:3,21) coming upon this ungodly system of things. Note,Peter draws a parallel with the flood of Noah in which the then "earth" and "heavens" (2 Peter 3:5-6) were destroyed, on that occasion only the rebellious wicked mankind was destroyed and the use of "heavens" refers to the human rulership of the ungodly.

Thus, the incurable wicked humankind will be gone, as will all wicked governments, which will be dissolved and replaced by God’s heavenly rule, or Kingdom.​ Daniel 2:44.  The planet earth will not come to its end, what will end is the symbolic earth, that is the wicked human society.

Proverbs 2:21-22  (KJV)

> 21 For the upright shall dwell in the land, and the perfect shall
> remain in it. 22 But the wicked shall be cut off from the earth, and
> the transgressors shall be rooted out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Throughout the New Testament, the word “elements” (stoicheia) is always used in connection with the Old Covenant order. The world of the Jews and Law- the first creation. St. Paul used the term in his stinging rebuke to the Galatian Christians who were tempted to forsake the freedom of the New Covenant for an Old Covenant-style legalism. Describing Old Covenant rituals and ceremonies, he says “we were in bondage under the elements (stoicheia) of this world. . . . How is it that you turn again to the weak and beggarly elements (stoicheia), to which you desire again to be in bondage? You observe days and months and seasons and years. . . .” (Gal. 4:3, 9–10). He warns the Colossians: “Beware lest anyone cheat you through philosophy and empty deceit, according to the basic principles (stoicheia) of the world, and not according to Christ. . . . Therefore, if you died with Christ to the basic principles (stoicheia) of the world, why, as though living in the world, do you subject yourselves to regulations—‘Do not touch, do not taste, do not handle’” (Col. 2:8, 20–21). The writer to the Hebrews chided them: “For though by this time you ought to be teachers, you have need again for someone to teach you the elements (stoicheia) of the oracles of God, and you have come to need milk and not solid food” (Heb. 5:12). In context, the writer to the Hebrews is clearly speaking of Old Covenant [elements that the book of Hebrews argues have passed away]—particularly since he connects it with the term oracles of God, an expression used elsewhere in the New Testament for the provisional, Old Covenant revelation (see Acts 7:38; Rom. 3:2). These citations from Galatians, Colossians, and Hebrews comprise all the other occurrences in the New Testament of that word “elements” (stoicheia). 
Not one refers to the “elements” of the physical world or universe; all are speaking of the “elements” of the Old Covenant system, which, as the apostles wrote just before the approaching destruction of the Old Covenant Temple in A. D. 70, was “becoming obsolete and growing old” and “ready to vanish away” (Heb. 8:13). And St. Peter uses the same term in exactly the same way. Throughout the Greek New Testament, the word “elements” (stoicheia) always means [covenantal elements], not [physical elements]; the foundational “elements” of a religious system that was doomed to pass away in a fiery judgment [Matt. 22:7].

Comment: V5&7 make reference to the physical earth and the actual heavens (Biblical cosmology evidently). So how does that fit in with your none physical explanation of the word? They are translated as heavenly bodies not covenantal elements. (I’m not saying that this word doesn’t ALSO refer to covenantal elements)

Comment: Your opening sentence is factually incorrect and contracts the analysis that follows.  Col 2:20 is nothing to do with OT covenants.  Heb 5:12 is the very opposite of OT covenant theology.

Comment: I do not think that it is factually incorrect. Please explain?

Comment: You said, "Throughout the New Testament, the word “elements” (stoicheia) is always used in connection with the Old Covenant order".  Col 2:20 and Heb 5:12 are nothing to do with the Old Covenant order.  This is also confirmed by BDAG.  Please base you answer on some solid evidence.

Comment: Seems to me that Col 2:20 and Heb 5:12 are ALL about the Old Covenant world. Heb 5:12 Is Paul asking why do Christians live by the dead Old Covenant rules when they are no longer in bondage to them.

Answer (score 2):

The dispute about what στοιχεῖον (stoicheion) means in the various places in the NT has vexed many commentators for a long time and this question is unlikely to resolve it.  Even the venerable BDAG is highly equivocal about the various shades of meaning here.  What we do know is that στοιχεῖον (stoicheion) occurs just seven times in the NT and does NOT always mean exactly the same thing as shown below.

- In places like Wsd 7:17, 19:18, 4 Macc 12:13, etc, στοιχεῖον (stoicheion) does mean the classic four elements of earth, air fire, water.
- BDAG also list several places outside the NT where some of the constellations are referred to using the same word στοιχεῖον (stoicheion)
- Gal 4:3, 9 appear to use στοιχεῖον (stoicheion) to describe elementary principles of philosophy and human nature in combination with Old Covenant legalism
- Col 2:20 discusses something similar without any suggestion of OT covenants involved.  That is, στοιχεῖον (stoicheion) describes worldly philosophy that Christ is so opposed to.
- Heb 5:12, by contrast, στοιχεῖον (stoicheion) describes elementary principles of Christian teaching.
- 2 Peter 3:10, 12 is the question at hand as it discusses "the Day of the Lord" and the end of the world in future conflagration language.  It is yet to come but will arrive as a thief in the night.  We note that wherever στοιχεῖον (stoicheion) is or are, in addition the heavens, the earth, and its works will also be destroyed, by burning (or "intense heat" v12) and a great "roar".

In Peter's usage, as with others in the NT, στοιχεῖον (stoicheion) cannot simply refer to earth, air, fire and water as the meaning is stretched to include many other things as shown elsewhere in the NT.  Nor could it include fire as fire does not destroy fire.  Earth is also specifically listed separately.

Note the simple structure of 1 Peter 3:10 -

> But the day of the Lord will come like a thief in which:
>
> 1. the heavens will pass away with a roar
> 2. the elements will be destroyed/melted with intense heat
> 3. the earth and its works will be destroyed

It is difficult to escape the all-encompassing nature of this list as completely removing our entire world and everything in it to be replaced by a "new heavens and a new earth wherein dwells righteousness."  Thus, it appears that while "heaven and earth" certainly refer to the physical things that will be destroyed on the day of the Lord, στοιχεῖον (stoicheion) here refers to worldly philosophy (Col 2:20) and all the physical things that philosophy has created.

Thus, στοιχεῖον (stoicheion) is part of an all-encompassing list of everything in our present world to be destroyed in preparation for the God's new order and new world.

Comment: John 14:3 " And if I go and make ready a place for you, I will return and take you to be with me, that where I am you also may be". Seem to indicate that heaven exists today somewhere outside the realm of this earth, and that there is where we eventually are going.

Comment: Correct - the heavens in 2 Peter 3:10 is presumably the aerial heavens.

Comment: Paul said that he had been to the 3d heaven (2 Cor 12:2). Makes one wonder if the "heavens" that will burn up, according to 2 Peter 3:10, are the 1st and 2nd heavens, and if the reference to "heavens being rolled up like a scroll" in Rev 6:14 (NIV) refers to this same event?

Comment: The Greek word for heaven here is “ouranos” it has been translated both “heavens” and “heaven”. Thus, it doesn’t have to be in plural and might just refer to the first heaven.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of 2 Peter 3, the word kosmos refers to an "order" or "system". *The stoichea are not the physical components of that system but the fundamental principles by which a system operates.*

For example, written language has its "ABCs" as its stoichea and electricity has Ohm's Law.

Judaism of the 2nd temple period focused on law and [orthopraxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthopraxy).

Law:

> Law is a system of rules that are created and enforced through social or governmental institutions to regulate behavior.[2] It has been defined both as "the Science of Justice" and "the Art of Justice".[3][4] Law is a system that regulates and ensures that individuals or a community adhere to the will of the state. State-enforced laws can be made by a collective legislature or by a single legislator, resulting in statutes, by the executive through decrees and regulations, or established by judges through precedent, normally in common law jurisdictions. Private individuals can create legally binding contracts, including arbitration agreements that may elect to accept alternative arbitration to the normal court process. The formation of laws themselves may be influenced by a constitution, written or tacit, and the rights encoded therein. The law shapes politics, economics, history and society in various ways and serves as a mediator of relations between people....

Orthopraxy:

> ...In the study of religion, orthopraxy is correct conduct, both ethical and liturgical, as opposed to faith or grace etc.[1][2][3] This contrasts with orthodoxy, which emphasizes correct belief, and ritualism, the practice of rituals.[4] The word is a neoclassical compound—ὀρθοπραξία (orthopraxia) meaning 'correct practice'.

> While orthodoxies make use of codified beliefs, in the form of creeds, and ritualism more narrowly centers on the strict adherence to prescribed rites or rituals, orthopraxy is focused on issues of family, cultural integrity, the transmission of tradition, sacrificial offerings, concerns of purity, ethical system, and the enforcement thereof.[5][6]...

In addition, other principles came into the picture including sin and death.

However, for Paul, the fundamental principles aka stoichea by which his gospel works is faith in God/Christ/Scripture apart from the activities of Torah, faithfulness verse rituals, and the breath of life. I'll just point out his teaching about the breath of life:

> [Rom 8:2 NASB] (2) For the law of the Spirit of life in Christ Jesus has set you free from the law of sin and of death.

Which is better translated thus:

> [Rom 8:2 NASB] (2) For the *principle* of the *breath of life* in Christ Jesus has set you free from the *principle* of sin and of death.

UPDATE

This is an allusion to:

> [Isa 34:4 NLT] (4) The heavens above will melt away and disappear like a rolled-up scroll. The stars will fall from the sky like withered leaves from a grapevine, or shriveled figs from a fig tree.

This was originally written about the invasion of Edom! This makes it perfectly clear that it is hyperbole and metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

The elements that God melted were the principles of the Mosaic temple worship system under the old covenant.  They were not referring to the physical cosmos.  Excerpt from my post "Frequent Mistakes - Part VI: The End of The World...?"  -

Peter opens chapter 3 of his second epistle with the reminder of God’s judgment upon the wicked.  The context is of God’s judgments against wicked men.  Verse 10 specifically uses the indicator of prophesy – “the day of the Lord.”  Upon seeing those words from... OT prophesy, we immediately know that we need to be watching for His prophetic metaphors.

“**heavens shall pass away**”

The kingdoms of men were and are “heavens” under the authority of Christ whose everlasting kingdom is over all the earthly kingdoms of men (Dan. 7:14, 27), which earthly kingdoms are the only “heavens” that can pass away.   The heaven where God sits on His throne will never pass away. See the previous post “Heaven and Earth Have Passed Away” [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2015/08/26/heaven-earth-have-passed-away/).

“**the elements shall melt**”

Strong’s Gr. 4747 “στοιχεῖον” transliterated as “stoicheion” and it means one of a row, hence a letter (of the alphabet), by ext. the elements (of knowledge).  The elements are the fundamentals, an orderly arrangement like the basic components of philosophy, structure, or first principles. It refers to the elements and rudiments of religious training and the ceremonial precepts of worship.  (See [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/greek/4747.htm))

It is used in the context of being in bondage under the elements of the law in Gal. 4:3-5. The word is rendered as “rudiments” in Col. 2:8, 20 where the traditions of men, and ordinances of men are discussed.  It is translated as “principles” in Heb. 5:12 for the first principles of the gospel.

As Part V of this series showed, “heaven and earth” was a compound metaphor for the Mosaic covenant.  This prophesy in 2 Pet. 3 is discussing the passing away which Christ prophesied in Matt. 24:35 in the context of the destruction of the temple at Jerusalem.

“Heaven and earth shall pass away, but my words shall not pass away.”  (KJV)

Christ’s words – the gospel, the new covenant, the new heaven and earth were compared to the old heaven and earth of the Mosaic covenant which was about to pass away in that first century A.D.  If you need to, please read Part V of this series again.

Instead of staying with the definition of Strong’s Gr. 4747, all of the commentaries I have read on 2 Pet. 3:10 either incorporated the dispensationalist teaching of the millennium – which the posts on this site have provided much scriptural evidence against, and which false doctrine therefore could not have been God’s intent – or they followed the traditional writings of the early church fathers such as Justin, or incorporated Greek philosophy of the four elements of the material creation, or were grasping upon faulty misconceptions of other prophetic language for the signs of the sun, moon and stars.

The commentators did not keep to the definition of the word “stoicheion.”  They read their belief system into the scriptures instead of relying only upon God’s word. A blind adherence to a belief system has caused this confusion regarding 2 Peter c. 3.
.....

Contrary to Thayer’s Greek Lexicon and most commentaries, **the elements that melted were not the elements of the material creation, but were instead the religious and ceremonial principles, the orderly arrangement of the worship of God under the old law of the Mosaic covenant.**   ......

The word translated as “melt” in the KJV is Strong’s Gr. 3089, ” λύω” transliterated as “luo” and means (a) I loose, untie, release, (b) met: I break, destroy, set at naught, contravene; I break up a meeting, annul.”  Thayer’s Lexicon attributes the definition of “to destroy” in verse 10, but for the same word in verse 12 it assigns “to overthrow or do away with.” (1)

God was overthrowing, setting loose, breaking up, putting away, annulling (Heb 7:18) the old Mosaic covenant!

**“the earth also and the works that are therein”**

In God’s prophetic language “the earth” was the people and the land to whom the prophet was speaking.  This is the same “earth” that Christ was sent to – Israel.  This is the same “earth” that He sent His disciples to, and whom he warned would not finish going through the cities of Israel before He came again (Matt. 10:23).

The “earth” is God’s footstool (Isa. 66:1), and God cast the beauty of Israel down from “heaven unto the earth” and did not remember His footstool (Lam. 2:1).  In OT prophesy, “earth” most often represented the land of Israel.

Just so, the “earth” and the “works therein”  of 2 Pet. 3:10 was the remnant of Israel: Judea, Jerusalem, and the animal sacrificial sin offerings at the temple which had become profane after Christ’s once and forever sacrifice on the cross.

Heb. 9:26, *“ For then must he often have suffered since the foundation of the world: but now once in the end of the world hath he appeared to put away sin by the sacrifice of himself.”*  (KJV)

When did He appear? When was Christ crucified?  And, when did He put away sin by His sacrifice?  Let’s read it again in Young’s Literal Translation.

> “since it had behoved him many times to suffer from the foundation of the world, but now once, at the full end of the ages, for putting away of sin through his sacrifice, he hath been manifested;”  (YLT)

The English translators used “end of the world” incorrectly in the KJV.  It was the end of their world as they knew it.. the end of the world that centered around that old Mosaic temple, but it was not literally the end of all life on earth!

The full end of the ages occurred when Christ was sacrificed for our sins in the first century A.D., [and when He subsequently returned in AD 70 to "melt" the works at that temple in Jerusalem.] That was when He was manifested in “these last days” (1 Pet 1:20), and those were the last days… of the old covenant.

The double fulfillment of Ezek 22:18-22 –

> *“18 Son of man, the house of Israel is to me become dross: all they are brass, and tin, and iron, and lead, in the midst of the furnace; they are even the dross of silver. 19 Therefore thus saith the Lord God; Because ye are all become dross, behold, therefore I will gather you into the midst of Jerusalem.*
>
> *"20 As they gather silver, and brass, and iron, and lead, and tin, into the midst of the furnace, to blow the fire upon it, to melt it; so will I gather you in mine anger and in my fury, and I will leave you there, and melt you. 21 Yea, I will gather you, and blow upon you in the fire of my wrath, and ye shall be melted in the midst therof.*
>
> *22 As silver is melted in the midst of the furnace, **so shall ye be melted in the midst thereof**; and ye shall know that I the Lord have poured out my fury upon you.”* (KJV)
>
> *“He hath bent his bow like an enemy: he stood with his right hand as an adversary, and slew all that were pleasant to the eye in the tabernacle of the daughter of Zion: he poured out his fury like fire.”*  (Lam. 2:4, KJV)

Brass, tin, iron, lead, silver… these are all physical, natural elements that can be melted in a fiery furnace.  Here, “melt” is Strong’s Heb. 5413, ” נָתַך” or “nathak”, and means poured out.  Melting the elements allows them to be reshaped and reformed. God’s judgment upon wicked men is poured out like fire.  The word “like” indicates a METAPHOR!  (2)

God’s fury – judgment – was poured out like fire, burning the elements of those sinful, wicked men in A.D. 70 at that temple in Jerusalem for sacrificing His son (Rev. 1:7) and for continuing, even preferring the animal sacrifices of the Mosaic covenant in that temple (Rev. 2:9; 3:9)!

God’s fury “melted” those people in Jerusalem in the Roman siege of A.D. 70 just as surely as He “melted” the fundamental and orderly principles (elements) of the Mosaic covenant in the destruction of the temple.

The rest of the post is at my blog [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/04/28/frequent-mistakes-part-vi-the-end-of-the-world-or/)

Notes:

1) Strong's Gr. 3089 "luo" - [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/str/greek/3089.htm)

2) Strong's Heb. 5413 "nathak" - [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/5413.htm)

Comment: Seems like you’ve spiritualized the whole concept and put a preterist?!? Twist on the answer? How does this fit in with earlier verses namely 5 &7 that actually refers to the physical creation of the Biblical Cosmological Creation? Why is it contrasted to Creation and the world wide flood of Noah but suddenly now it’s not physical? Did I miss something?

Comment: Did the world wide flood of Noah's day destroy the world?  Or just the people?  Was the physical cosmos still remaining after the flood?  The judgment fell upon wicked ppl.  Gen 8:21,"... I will not again curse the ground any more for man's sake; ..."   The rainbow around the throne scene in Rev. 4 remembers God's promise, & indicated a limited judgment - not a world wide destruction.

Comment: According to the Bible water rose and covered the highest mountain for many months leading to the death of anything that lived on land including the birds. That was a physical event with physical consequences and while it didn’t include the heavens or the seas or below the earth it was definitely world wide. The rainbow was an indication God will never again destroy the earth/land Hebrew with water but this is destruction with fire. So God is honoring the rainbow promise by not using water.

Comment: The first promise in Gen 8 was not qualified "by water".  It was an unqualified promise.  Fire is a metaphor God used in His prophesy for judgment.  You can substitute God's judgment whenever you see "fire" in a prophesy.  In fact, He has used both water as a flood and fire in the same verse for destruction of a nation / people. (Mic. 1:4).  This fire in Peter is another prophesy of His judgment against the wicked of Jerusalem and that temple which He poured out in AD 70.  See that same rainbow around the throne in Ezek 1:28 for the judgment against Jerusalem.  Nation / land / region only.

Comment: “I will remember my covenant that is between me and you and every living creature of all flesh. And the **waters** shall never again become a **flood** to **destroy all flesh**.”
‭‭Genesis‬ ‭9:15‬

Comment: Hey Gina, long time no chat. I just added this to my answer and you may want to add it to yours:  This is an allusion to:

*[Isa 34:4 NLT] (4) The heavens above will melt away and disappear like a rolled-up scroll. The stars will fall from the sky like withered leaves from a grapevine, or shriveled figs from a fig tree.*
This was originally written about the invasion of Edom! This makes it perfectly clear that it is hyperbole and metaphor.

Comment: Great point, Ruminator.  Lots of OT judgment language needs to be looked at from the proper perspective.  In prophesy, the heavens were alluding to the rulers and authorities who held dominion over that land.  They were a type of God's heaven above, as they ruled their territory at His will.  So, their heavens were rolled up like scroll when God removed them from power, and their authority ceased.  Their record on their scroll was finished.

Answer (score 1):

Peace.

The “elements” spoken of are the fundamental principles or established precedents that men have put into handwritten documents such as the constitutions of the world to be governed by.   The Constitution of the United States is an example of a constitution.

The “rudiments”….the elements…of the world are these documents that men abide by…and fight over.

We, as His people, are supposed to separate from the world in these things yet we see that certain(fleshly-minded) men  have introduced these type of handwritings (of ordinances/dogmas) into the churches where they should not be.  People use them then to fight each other over.    Person vs person…church vs church, etc.    Their tradition (transmission) of men is handed down from one generation to another and there they have stayed.

> Colossians 2:8 KJV (8)  Beware lest any man spoil you through
>   philosophy and vain deceit, after the tradition of men, **after the
>   rudiments of the world, and not after Christ.**

The elements/ fundamental principles of the world are produced by men to govern…..they are the “powers and principalities” set up in the high places.

> Constitution:   a body of fundamental principles or established
>   precedents according to which a state or other organization is
>   acknowledged to be governed

.

> Tenet:  a principle or belief, especially one of the main principles
>   of a religion or philosophy.

His people are not to walk in the “manners “of the nations…that is, putting the outside world’s style of constitutions/documents into the churches where they should not be.

We are instead to keep God’s statutes and His Judgments within our church gatherings and not come up with our own handwritings which are patterned after the world's documents to govern ourselves by.   We are under God’s government and not the handwriting of the church dogmas which were scribed by fleshly-minded men who have no understanding. Why be subject to the elements of the world?

> Leviticus 20:22-23 KJV (22)  Ye shall therefore keep all my statutes,
>   and all my judgments, and do them: that the land, whither I bring you
>   to dwell therein, spue you not out. (23)  And ye shall not walk in the
>   manners of the nation, which I cast out before you: for they committed
>   all these things, and therefore I abhorred them.

Yet, we find almost all churches have some sort of handwriting of ordinances (dogmas contained in “tenets of faith”, statements of faith, church constitutions, church by-laws, creeds, etc ) within their gatherings and are highly esteemed by all who willingly subject themselves to them.   They serve and worship them all in the name of God who did not write them.

Many church constitutions include a phrase such as  “we voluntarily and solemnly submit ourselves” to their church constitutions in the preamble of them.

If we are dead with Christ from the rudiments (elements) of the world, why are then subject to ordinances….the handwritings of church dogmas that God did not write nor did He speak it nor did it come to HIs mind?  They are patterned after the world’s handwritings.

Men….fleshly-minded men…have written these things and have placed them in the high places  of their churches for their congregations to serve and worship.   They do not have the mind of Christ as they would not have written them if they did.  They do not hold the Head but they thought they understood something when they did not.

> Colossians 2:20-23 KJV (20)  **Wherefore if ye be dead with Christ from
>   the rudiments of the world, why, as though living in the world, are ye
>   subject to ordinances**,

We perish with the using of them.  These documents include the commandments and doctrines of men that do not save anyone that submit themselves to them.  Many think that the church “dogmas”….what one thinks is right….save but they do not.

> (21)  *(Touch not; taste not; handle not; (22)  **Which all are to perish
>   with the using;) after the commandments and doctrines of men?** (23) 
>   Which things have indeed a shew of wisdom in will worship, and
>   humility, and neglecting of the body; not in any honour to the
>   satisfying of the flesh.*

It is worshipping and serving the “creature” (the ordinance, the formation….the formation of the handwriting) more than the Creator.  The woman in the garden added her own commandment (…”neither shall you touch it,,,”to God’s commandment and then presented it as though He said it when He did not.   They change the truth of God into THE Lie…the same lie from the beginning.  They think themselves as “gods”…that is, judges for God…who know what and who is good or evil according to their own standards….the church dogmas…and speak evil of others who do not do them.

> Romans 1:25 KJV (25)  Who changed the truth of God into a lie, **and
>   worshipped and served the creature more than the Creator,** who is
>   blessed for ever. Amen.

People worship Him in vain as they serve instead the handwriting of the doctrines of the commandments of men.   They lay aside the commandment of God (who commanded us to have love for one another) in order to hold the “tradition”….the transmission of men…. who have handed down their handwritings of church dogmas through generations.

> Mark 7:7-9 KJV (7)  ***Howbeit in vain do they worship me, teaching for
>   doctrines the commandments of men. (8)  For laying aside the
>   commandment of God, ye hold the tradition of men,*** as the washing of
>   pots and cups: and many other such like things ye do. (9)  And he said
>   unto them, Full well ye reject the commandment of God, that ye may
>   keep your own tradition.

The keeping of the handwritings of church ordinances “burn” us in the fire.  The “elements” ….the church principles we adhere to…. melt us with fervent heat as we use them in our lives to judge others with . We perish with the using up of them and all of the keeping of their “works” that we have done all of our lives to serve the handwritings burn up also when we perish from this earth as the heavens come alongside to get us in the day of our death with a “great noise”….that is, with a whirring sound.  This whirring sound is the sound of a whirlwind in the great day of the Lord’s wrath upon us in the day of our own death.

> 2 Peter 3:9-10 KJV (9)  The Lord is not slack concerning his promise,
>   as some men count slackness; but is longsuffering to us-ward, not
>   willing that any should perish, but that all should come to
>   repentance.

Our keeping of church principles/dogmas do not do anything for preserving the mortal body in this earth as they dissolve away as we leave this earth for our sins.   The works do not preserve us as we then leave them all behind as the whirlwind of God’s wrath takes us away.

> (10)  But the day of the Lord will come as a thief in the night; in
>   the which the heavens shall pass away with a great noise, **and the
>   elements shall melt with fervent heat, the earth also and the works
>   that are therein shall be burned up.**

We suffer loss by building upon the Foundation of Jesus Christ the elements of the doctrines and commandments of men (the “wood, hay, stubble”) which do not save the mortal body in this earth as they all burn up in the day of God’s wrath which is revealed from Heaven.  Men preach things (their handwritings of dogmas which are wood, hay, stubble) that they should not be teaching for filthy lucre’s sake (gold, silver, precious stones).

> 1 Corinthians 3:11-20 KJV (11)  For other foundation can no man lay
>   than that is laid, which is Jesus Christ. (12)  **Now if any man build
>   upon this foundation gold, silver, precious stones, wood, hay,
>   stubble; (13)  Every man's work shall be made manifest: for the day
>   shall declare it, because it shall be revealed by fire; and the fire
>   shall try every man's work of what sort it is**. (14)  If any man's work
>   abide which he hath built thereupon, he shall receive a reward.

If we serve and worship their church handwritings, then our work shall burn up as we suffer loss:  the  loss of the eternal life of Jesus in this earth.  **Do not let a man beguile you of your reward:**  the appearing life of Jesus in this current mortal body which will give us His eternal life.

> (15)  **If any man's work shall be burned, he shall suffer loss: but he
>   himself shall be saved; yet so as by fire.** (16)  Know ye not that ye
>   are the temple of God, and that the Spirit of God dwelleth in you?
>   (17)  **If any man defile the temple of God, him shall God destroy; for
>   the temple of God is holy, which temple ye are**. (18)  Let no man
>   deceive himself. If any man among you seemeth to be wise in this
>   world, let him become a fool, that he may be wise. (19)  For the
>   wisdom of this world is foolishness with God. For it is written, He
>   taketh the wise in their own craftiness. (20)  And again, The Lord
>   knoweth the thoughts of the wise, that they are vain.

Answer (score 1):

The "elements" are simply all the things that comprise the surface of the Earth.

Most of the Bible's holy festivals are based on a common theme of harvest, a metaphor for God harvesting the saved from humanity and burning the remnants.
(Separating the wheat from the chaff.)

John was given a vision of this end-time harvest:

> And another angel came out of the temple, crying with a loud voice to Him who sat on the cloud, “Thrust in Your sickle and reap, for the time has come for You to reap, for the harvest of the earth is ripe.” — Revelation 14:15

Malachi 4:1–3 is a prophecy of this end-time event:

> “For behold, the day is coming,
> Burning like an oven,
> And all the proud, yes, all who do wickedly will be stubble.
> And the day which is coming shall burn them up,”
> Says the LORD of hosts,
> “That will leave them neither root nor branch.
> …
> You shall trample the wicked,
> For they shall be ashes under the soles of your feet
> On the day that I do this,”
> Says the LORD of hosts.

John the Baptist spoke of Jesus's purpose:

> “I indeed baptize you with water unto repentance, but He who is coming after me is mightier than I, whose sandals I am not worthy to carry. He will baptize you with the Holy Spirit and fire.
> His winnowing fan is in His hand, and He will thoroughly clean out His threshing floor, and gather His wheat into the barn; but He will burn up the chaff with unquenchable fire.” — Matthew 3:11–12 (and Luke 3:16–17)

Jesus himself made reference to it when explaining a parable:

> He answered and said to them: “He who sows the good seed is the Son of Man.
> “The field is the world, the good seeds are the sons of the kingdom, but the tares are the sons of the wicked one.
> The enemy who sowed them is the devil, the harvest is the end of the age, and the reapers are the angels.
> Therefore as the tares are gathered and burned in the fire, so it will be at the end of this age.
> The Son of Man will send out His angels, and they will gather out of His kingdom all things that offend, and those who practice lawlessness, and will cast them into the furnace of fire. …" — Matthew 13:37–42

And in another:

> “I am the vine, you are the branches. He who abides in Me, and I in him, bears much fruit; for without Me you can do nothing.
> If anyone does not abide in Me, he is cast out as a branch and is withered; and they gather them and throw them into the fire, and they are burned. — John 15:6

As mentioned in the question:

> But the day of the Lord will come as a thief in the night, in which the heavens will pass away with a great noise, and the elements will melt with fervent heat; both the earth and the works that are in it will be burned up. — 2Peter 3:10

This total destruction of the surface of the Earth is also referred to as the "lake of fire":

> Then Death and Hades were cast into the lake of fire. This is the second death.
> And anyone not found written in the Book of Life was cast into the lake of fire. — Revelation 20:14–15
>
> “He who overcomes shall inherit all things, and I will be his God and he shall be My son.
> But the cowardly, unbelieving, abominable, murderers, sexually immoral, sorcerers, idolaters, and all liars shall have their part in the lake which burns with fire and brimstone, which is the second death.” — Revelation 21:7–8